# VBA: Copy first value of each month

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a data set and from the daily data have managed to compute the average for each month.

My data looks like this: column B (and A) are dates, column C is the daily temperature and column E is the average monthly temperature, while column D is daily precipitation and column F is average monthly precipitation. Then the structure repeats itself for the next city starting in column G. [image: Here]

I would like to copy the average temperature for each month (and each city) into a new sheet, where each row is a city and each column is a separate month (with monthly date in column A in the data above as header), which should look something like this:

[image]

Finally I would like to do the same for the average monthly precipitation, but on a new sheet. If I can solve this for temperature, then precipitation can be solved the same way.

I have tried to filter away any duplicates but because multiple months have no rainfall I cant use that method. Have also tried to use VLOOKUP without success.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `AVERAGEIFS` is what you are looking for. Print the city name down `A` in your new sheet, take the months and remove duplicates, then transpose them across `1`, and for the interior of the table it's `AVERAGEIFS` for values matching the city name and month heading. You do not need VBA for this.

Comment: I have tried using AVERAGEIFS too, could you please show me how you would do it?

Comment: Than you Alex, it did work!! for future readers I used: ``=AVERAGEIFS($E:$E,$A:$A,Sheet2!B$1)``

Comment: where column E is the temp, column A are the dates (both in top picture), and cell B1 is the specific date (here 20151) in my second output sheet.

Comment: @litmus,, I'm unable to understand the reason behind this exercise since for each city recorded temperature are similar no variation,, then what does the Average temperate do , since the formula return the same value as an Average for each month !!

Comment: @RajeshS if you look carefully you will see that there are small variations. The reason for this exercise is to change the layout of the data from the first picture into the layout of the second picture. But please note that Alex already gave me a solution above.

Comment: @litmus ,, I've seen properly,, every entire month have same value changes in next month but again 30 duplicates,, the easiest should getting Unique for each set and transpose it !!

Comment: @RajeshS As stated in the last sentence of my question, I cant use unique because multiple months have value "0", and those need to be kept, but otherwise it may have worked

Comment: @litmus, while creating Unique list you may skip Blanks & Zeros as well as you can keep them also !!